# Overwrite variables.scss in gem Bootstrap 4.1.3 Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-4

I am running Rails 5.1 with the `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'` and I want to activate gradients and the shadows in the application.

For now, there is no gradient on the inputs :

[image]

I would like to get this appearance (a shadow and not a solid border) :

[image]

I suppose it'is linked to the default variables in _variables.scss  (inside the gem)

```
$enable-shadows:            false !default;
$enable-gradients:          false !default;
```

I don't want to modidy the bootstrap gem itself, so I tried to add the following in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`

```
/* Trying to overwrite CSS default variables in SCSS */
$enable-shadows: true;
$enable-gradients: true;
/* Vendor CSS */
@import "bootstrap";
@import "fontawesome-all";
@import "selectize.js-master/dist/css/selectize";
@import "selectize.js-master/dist/css/selectize.bootstrap4";
@import "jquery-ui/autocomplete.css";
@import "devise";
/* My CSS */
@import "colors";
@import "global";
@import "items";
@import "posts";
@import "tags";
@import "users";
@import "welcome";
```

but there is no effect on the input gradient... What do I miss ?

Bootstrap doc variable overwrite : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults

Comment: Sprockets directives and Sass don't play well together, so make sure you get rid of `*= require_tree` etc. https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note

Comment: @max OK, I changed my imports as you proposed (see updated application.scss content)... But I still get no gradient...

Comment: I just pointed the sprockets directives out to spare you some headaches down the road. You could try exporting the variables to a file and then importing it, just in case the `@import` directives are being hoisted.